# Transitive is not replicated to Inverse property

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

Protege 5.5.0

I made two properties, the second I made InverseOf first property.

When I check the Transitive on any of the property, Transitive on another doesn't appear.

I'm newby in Ontology, the book I'm reading saying that it should appear in Protege 4.1.

Is that something new in Protege 5.5.0, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/272. You need something like https://github.com/matentzn/inference-inspector.